# Ubuntu Server 10.04 will not connect to the internet

Tags: networking, server, 10.04, virtualbox, ssd

I created an dd image from a VirtualBox with Ubuntu server 10.04 on it. Then I placed that image on a fresh empty ssd. My internet was working just fine on that virtualbox but on the ssd it doesnt connect to my ethernet cable. The pc with the ssd is connected to internet and I can do anything on it using a bootable cd.

`ifconfig` shows only local `loopback`

`ifconfig -a` shows also `eth1` but no `eth0`

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the virtual machine was configured to use the virtual network cable, since you've moved it to physical hardware the connection isn't available. You will need to edit your connection to use the new network connection as it's default.

Step #1 = In terminal type "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces". It should say "# The primary network interface","auto eth0","iface eth0 inet dhcp". Change all
the "eth0" entries to say "eth1". Exit using "cntrl + x" and press "enter" to save (ignore the options listed when saving, just press enter).

Step #2 = In terminal type "sudo ifup eth0".

Step #3 = In terminal type "ping example.djun.net". If succesful your screen will fill with somthing along the lines of "64 bytes from ip-" related outputs.
press "cntrl + c" to stop pinging. You are done! If you didn't successfully ping the server the proceed to next step.

Step #4 = In terminal type "sudo ifdown eth0", then in terminal type "sudo ifup eth0". Now retry pinging by typing in terminal "ping example.djun.net". You
should be done!